# How can advance google closure compilation be used with ES6 classes and arbitrary defineProperty?

Tags: google-closure-compiler

I maintain a data flow library that allows programmers to define new properties during instantiation, then does neat things at run-time with both property reads and writes, all transparently thanks to JS `defineProperty`. Sample usage, where `TagSession` is defined with the ES6 `class` keyword:

```
const sithApp = new TagSession( null, 'SithTrakSession',
    {
        obiTrakker: cF( c => new WebSocket('ws://localhost:4000')
            .onmessage = msg => c.md.obiLoc = JSON.parse(msg.data)),
        obiLoc: cI( null),
        sithIds: cI([-1,-2,3616,-3,-4])
    });
```

I can now write code where the map keywords are transparent accessors:

```
function SithTrak () {
    return div({class: "app-container"},
        h1({
            class: "css-planet-monitor",
            content: cF(c => "Obi-Wan currently on " +
                (sithApp.obiLoc ?
                    sithApp.obiLoc.name : "...dunno"))
        }))
}
```

This works great uncompiled and with Google Closure SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATION, but ADVANCED_COMPILATION warns (and the output fails) about, eg:

```
WARNING - Property obiLoc never defined on TagSession
            withObi: cF( c=> c.md.info && sithApp.obiLoc
```

I have looked at all the annotations that might apply, but nothing seems suited to such a dynamic capability.

Am I missing something obvious, or is this combo of dynamism and optimization asking too much?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic properties added with this method would require using a bracket access for ADVANCED mode: `sithApp['obiLoc']`. In ADVANCED mode, the compiler must know about all properties accessed via the dot nation at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Since it isn't known that these properties are defined on the class you are going to get type warnings, bit it shouldn't break your code.

You can add declarations to silence the type warnings:

`/** @type {?} */
TagSession.prototype.objLoc;`

In other cases, you might be able to use `@lends` but I don't think this will work here as the types provided might not match the expected type of the property value.  But there isn't enough context to be sure:

`/** @lends {TagSession.prototype} */ ({
        obiTrakker: ...,
        obiLoc: ...,
        sithIds: ...
    })`